# Django Form. View form with models of logged user

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm doing simple to do app in django. I want user to have possibility to add boards and task (task is specified for board).

When user is adding task (form created with ModelForm ) there is possibility to choose from different boards but the form is showing all boards - for all users. I want it to show only boards of currently logged user. How can I do this? Would appreciate some help.

**models.py:**

```
class Board(models.Model):
    board_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    day = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    board_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.board_name


class Task(models.Model):
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    not_done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    task_board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_name
```

**forms.py:**

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        user = User.objects.get(username='admin')
        fields = ['task_name', 'task_board']
```

**views.py**

```
def add_task(request):
    if Board.objects.filter(board_user=request.user).exists():
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        # problem nadal nierozwiązany
        if request.method == "POST":
            form.instance.task_board.user = request.user
            if form.is_valid:
                form.save()
            return redirect('tasks-view')
    else:
        return redirect('tasks-view')
    return render(request, 'todo/task_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

A super simple method of doing something like that would be to just use Django's built-in authenticated system.

If you want to show something only to logged in users (in views):

```py
def view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        # do something
    else:
        return login      # example
```

In templates:

```html
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p> logged in </p>
{% else %}
    <p> not logged in </p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this does not solve my problem. User is logged  and i don't want to redirect user anywhere or anything. The problem is in form model. It shows field with option to choose (foreign key) of all models, not the one that user created.

Answer (score 0):

I think Task Model should have a OneToOneField which in this case should be task_board as shown below

```py
class Task(models.Model):
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    not_done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    task_board = models.OneToOneField(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_name
```